# How to convert .pxp files created by IgorPro

Tags: file-conversion

I was given a data file with the extension .pxp and told it was from the program IgorPro. I am looking to extract the data to a more reasonable format, say CSV, for use in other code. However, a quick glance at the file tells me that it looks to be in binary. Does anyone out there have any experience with these files and could suggest a way to extract the data without the original program?

Comment: It seems to be more than a data file, as such an experiment contains data, procedures, graphs and other things. If the file is binary, you need to export the data from Igor itself, but it only seems to have export methods for the graphs. Maybe you can ask the person who gave you the file to either help you with installing the program or giving you the data in a more human- and machine-readable format.

Comment: Igor doesn't seem to have a Linux version, and installing over Wine seems to be problematic. I'm was hoping there was a conversion utility out there that someone had used in the past.